# Pandas replace regex: why this negation does not work

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['0123_GRP_LE_BNS', 'ABC_GRP_BNS', 'DEF_GRP', '456A_GRP_SSA'], columns=['P'])
>>> df
                 P
0  0123_GRP_LE_BNS
1      ABC_GRP_BNS
2          DEF_GRP
3     456A_GRP_SSA
```

and want to remove characters appear after GRP if they are not '_LE', or remove characters after GRP_LE.

The desired output is:

```
0     0123_GRP_LE
1         ABC_GRP
2         DEF_GRP
3        456A_GRP
```

I used the following pattern matching. the ouput was not expected:

```
>>> df['P'].replace({r'(.*_GRP)[^_LE].*':r'\1', r'(.*GRP_LE)_.*':r'\1'}, regex=True)
0     0123_GRP_LE
1     ABC_GRP_BNS
2         DEF_GRP
3    456A_GRP_SSA
Name: P, dtype: object
```

Why the negation in r'(.*_GRP)[^_LE].*' does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make `_LE` optional?

```
df['P'].str.replace(r'(GRP(?:_LE)?).*', r'\1', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0    0123_GRP_LE
1        ABC_GRP
2        DEF_GRP
3       456A_GRP
Name: P, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

I find pythons string ops easier to work with and less error prone than regex; I think this does what you're looking for:

```
def strip_code(code_str):
    if "GRP_LE" in code_str:
        return "".join(code_str.partition("GRP_LE")[0:2])
    elif "GRP" in code_str:
        return "".join(code_str.partition("GRP")[0:2])
    return code_str


df.P.apply(strip_code)
```

output:

```
0    0123_GRP_LE
1        ABC_GRP
2        DEF_GRP
3       456A_GRP
Name: P, dtype: object
```

Comment: Not sure about the "*less error prone*", but I expect it to be much slower!

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I'd love to see. I think pandas string handling doesn't benefit the same way the numeric does from SIMD.  Feel free to add a comparison

Comment: That's a good question. I'm on my phone now, so it's hard to run tests, maybe tomorrow if I remember! +1 for the alternative in any case ;)